# How to force MySQL Workbench to use constraints in my file?

Tags: mysql, constraint, mysql-workbench

I'm currently working on a project that requires I write my own constraints for my database (to show I know how they work). I'm attempting to test them in MySQL Workbench however the programs settings keep kicking in and overriding the SQL in my document. As a test I am setting all `DELETE`'s and `UPDATE`'s to `CASCADE` however in the settings it is set to `NO ACTION` and I am getting error messages.

[image: Settings Page]

I am under the assumption that the above is the correct settings page to alter but there is no "DO NOTHING I WANT TO USE MY OWN SETTINGS" option. Is there a way around this? I am trying to emulate another environment which honours no constraints at all to ensure that mine as working.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand the trouble you have. These settings are just defaults. They are used when you create a relationship. But you can then change the actions to anything you like. MySQL Workbench won't change them automatically to something else.